# Send a really long string to asmx web service as a parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asmx

in my application, I am calling the JSON.stringify(canvas) method.

this generates a JSON but this JSON can be really, really long. Like 25000 characters plus. Also, to make it simple i convert this JSON into a AES encrypted string.

the issue i am having is how to send to an ASMX web service. if i add the string as a paramter, it throws HTTP 500 error.

what is the correct way to send such large data to a backend webservice.

is streaming or chunking an option.

any pointers will be most useful.

Comment: Please consider adding `asmx` and `.net` and/or any other relevant tags to the question.
Thank you!

Comment: thanks for the info, done!

Comment: You are welcome!
Good luck!

Comment: For sending large string, use `POST` instead of url parameter.

Comment: I am not sending a URL parameter. I am using POST. Here is my AJAX call...    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossOrigin: true,
        url: ServiceRoot + "service.asmx/SaveSession",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
                   return response;
        },
    });